# Change AuthenticationScheme to force another AuthenticationHandler to be fired

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, basic-authentication

We need to be able to support both Basic Authentication and Bearer Authentication. Bearer Authentication being the preferred / default method. Basic is for some clients that cannot support Bearer Authentication.

We want to be able to manage privileges from a since source. The idea is that if a user is using Basic Auth, that user would actually send us his clientId/clientSecret and we will get the token for him.

In order to keep this hole as closed as possible, clientId needs to be validated versus a whitelist first. How can I do that without have to completely re-implement the Bearer Authentication. Even if we whitelisted the clientId we still want to validate the token exactly like if they would have sent it.

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{

    public const string AuthTypeName = "Basic ";
    private const string _authHeaderName = "Authorization";

    public BasicAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers[_authHeaderName]);
        var (clientId, clientSecret) = DecodeUserIdAndPassword(authHeader.Parameter);
        if (!clientIdIsWhiteListed.IsSatisfiedBy(clientId))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Credentials");

        IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .Build();

        string[] scopes = new string[] { "MyScope" };
        var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

        // Here is where I have no clue how to continue
        Request.Headers[_authHeaderName] = $"Bearer {result.AccessToken}";  //?
        return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();                               //?
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not worked with Azure but looks like the authentication succeeded or not depends on the `result`. In case of success, the `AccessToken` is granted. The code there is almost done. You don't have to do anything. The `AccessToken` is added to the request header only if the authentication succeeds before (meaning the token is generated and valid).

Answer (score 0):

I was so close to the correct answer, well here is what I did and it works.
1 line change

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{

    public const string AuthTypeName = "Basic ";
    private const string _authHeaderName = "Authorization";

    public BasicAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers[_authHeaderName]);
        var (clientId, clientSecret) = DecodeUserIdAndPassword(authHeader.Parameter);
        if (!clientIdIsWhiteListed.IsSatisfiedBy(clientId))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Credentials");

        IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .Build();

        string[] scopes = new string[] { "MyScope" };
        var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

        Request.Headers[_authHeaderName] = $"Bearer {result.AccessToken}";
        return await Context.AuthenticateAsync("Bearer");
    }
}
```